# how to get attribute label if it's a price attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes

I'am trying to get all attribute label of a special attribute which type is "price". Here is my code but it's not retreiving the right value.

```
 $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', '170');
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
$table_screen = array();    
foreach ( $values  = $options->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())->setStoreFilter(1)->toOptionArray() as $option){
$table_screen[] = (int)$option['label'];
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Code

To get the Value of your custom attribute then

```
 $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
 print_r($option->getData('Your Attribute ID'));
```

To get the All values

```
 /**
 * @var $config  Mage_Eav_Model_Config
 * @var $options Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection
 */
$storeId   = 3;
$config    = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
$attribute = $config->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'color');
$values    = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions();
print_r($values);

//here is another method
$options = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection');
$values  = $options->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())->setStoreFilter($storeId)->toOptionArray();
print_r($values);
```

when you print this `$value` you got one array contain below one.

```
 Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [value] => 128
             [label] => test
         )
 )
```

Comment: My situation est more in the "another method" because I want a table with all the value of this attribute. However when it's a price type attribute it's not working. The right value is located in catalog_product_entity_decimal instead of the standard eav_attribute_option_value

Comment: yes this code will return all value of your attribute with label just copy and paste the code and change the store id and attribute code

Comment: I have tested it then and then I suggest you .

Comment: but you try with the color attribute which is not a price attribute.

Comment: buddy replace with your attribute code simple man..

Comment: I did replace the attribute code by my custom attribute name and I confirm you that it is not working. (although I can confirm you that this code is working for the "color" attribute)

Comment: It will return blank array because its type is price

Comment: I agree with you. This is precisely the purpose of my initial question. How can I do that if it's a price type attribute ?

Comment: you can do one thing you have to create new custom attribute for product and select type as drop down and you can create the options for that and you can try above code.

Comment: You have a point. I can easily duplicate this attribute. To explain, I need to have this attribute in price type on some other part on the website but I can create another attribute similar drop down type. I'm gonna try it. Thank you :)